# Printing mpq_t in GMP library

Tags: gmp

I've encountered a problem when trying to print mpq_t data type in GMP. Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <gmp.h>

    int main(){
        mpq_t a;
        mpq_init(a);
        mpq_set_str(a, "41/152", 10);
        gmp_printf("the rational is: %Q\n",a);
        return 0;
    }
```

But it only prints out "the rational is: Q". 
I've followed the GMP manual(https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Output-Strings.html), but couldn't find the bug. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please post your entire, short malfunctioning `.c` file, with the `main()` function, so others can easily reproduce the problem. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `d` (stands for *decimal*) is missing after the `Q`:

```
gmp_printf("the rational is: %Qd\n",a);
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem! Thank you very much!